# Outlook script used to download attachments stopped working

Tags: vba, outlook

I have a small script located below that I use to download attachments from emails that contain specific words in the subject.

It worked good for a while but recently I have been experiencing intermittent issues with it not downloading the attachments.

I'm starting to think the rule is the issue and not the script.

```
Sub saveAttachtoDisk(itm As Outlook.MailItem)
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment
Dim saveFolder As String
saveFolder = "path where to save file"
For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\inventory.csv"
Set objAtt = Nothing
Next
End Sub
```

This is the rule:

```
Apply this rule after the message arrives
with CPN in the subject
  and on this computer only
run Project1.saveAtachtoDisk
```

You guys are my last hope as nobody else can help me.

Answer (score 0):

Replace the rule with an event handler

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items 
Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal item As Object) 
  On Error Goto ErrorHandler 
  Dim Msg As Outlook.MailItem 
  If TypeName(item) = "MailItem" Then
    Set Msg = item 
    saveAttachtoDisk(Msg)
  End If
ProgramExit: 
  Exit Sub
ErrorHandler: 
  MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description 
  Resume ProgramExit 
End Sub
```

Comment: The ItemAdd event is not fired when multiple items are added (more than 16). The rule is the better way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add any logging statements to the VBA macro sub to make sure that the rule is triggered in Outlook. For example, you can create a text file and add log entries there.

> saveFolder = "path where to save file"

What exactly folder path is specified in the code?

```
For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments
  objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & "\inventory.csv"
```

It looks like you save attachments with the same name. In that case multiple attachments will be overwritten - only one file will be saved on the disk. Is that the case?

Comment: Yes, I want to overwrite the files. I'm only downloading a certain file and the old one it placed into a past file folder automatically by and FTP program. I just want to automatically download the file and automatically FTP it to my server(which currently works perfectly).