# Automatic downloading of e-mail attachments has stopped working

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2010

So, I had some pretty basic code to automatically download email attachments. It was working well for a good length of time, and has suddenly started to go on the fritz. A few notes:

1) It started to lightly go on the fritz a few weeks ago - simply re-running the rule would cause it to properly download everything. No problem, if we can restore it to this state I'd be happy.

2) Rules are stored client-side. We moved desks recently, which necessitated re-creating (read: Copy and pasting) all of our rules over as well. This worked ok for a few days - then the larger issues started - namely, it won't work at all. When I try to manually run the rule, it just "shorts out" after a few seconds - I suspect when it gets to the "Run macro" part. Automatic downloads don't work, manually running the rules don't work.

A few notes:

1) Macros are enabled
2) Macro security settings are on "Run all macros"
3) Code was stored in module 1, then in "ThisOutlookSession". Changing back and forth has had no impact
4) This has impacted several people - I've set up automatic downloading for a few different people, and we've all gone on the fritz. To be fair, I didn't set them up before we moved desks. I've attempted similar troubleshooting steps on two other computers. No luck. 
5) I can't use any programs besides the Microsoft office programs. Can't use Python, or any other type of external program.

Original code:

```
Public Sub SaveDownPriceFilesforMargin(itm As Outlook.MailItem)

Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment


Dim saveFolder As String


saveFolder = "FilePathHere"

     For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments

          objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & objAtt.DisplayName

          Set objAtt = Nothing
     Next
 End Sub
```

Current code iteration:

```
Public Sub SaveDownPriceFilesforMargin(itm As Outlook.MailItem)

On Error GoTo ErrorHandler
Dim objAtt As Outlook.Attachment

Dim dt As String

Dim saveFolder As String

dt = Format(Date, "MMDDYY")

saveFolder = "FilePathHere"

     For Each objAtt In itm.Attachments

          objAtt.SaveAsFile saveFolder & objAtt.DisplayName

          Set objAtt = Nothing
     Next
ProgramExit:
  Exit Sub
ErrorHandler:
  MsgBox Err.Number & " - " & Err.Description
  Resume ProgramExit

End Sub
```

To be clear, the main change I've made is the code I've found here: [Outlook script used to download attachments stopped working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29568612/outlook-script-used-to-download-attachments-stopped-working) . It hasn't caused the issue to resolve.

No error message is generated.

Edit: Occasionally a "Operation Failed" error message will generate when the rule catch the emails naturally. This error message doesn't run when I try to run the rule manually.

How can I get my automatic attachments working again?

And a side note, since I'm here: It'd be super nice to figure out how to take just the download name and get the extension separately - for example, ExcelFile.Xlsx gets parsed into "ExcelFile" and ".xslx" - but that's a separate, minor issue I can probably find with extensive googling.

Edit:

1) Stopped working - The rule will move the file over, but not download the file anymore. An error message occasionally pops up when the rule is triggered by an incoming email. No error message occurs when manually running the rules.

2) Edited the date out of the code

3) The path is an absolute path, defined in the code. I have permission to write to the folder in question, and have to manually save the files down to that location after.

4) Exchange setup changing - I've gotten no notifications that the exchange server has changed anything.

Comment: What does "stopped working" mean, exactly? Does the script run and quit (without saving anything?). Does the script never run? How do you call this script? Did anything change on your Outlook server? What exactly is "the rule"? Some more details will help with troubleshooting...

Comment: Incidentally - you set variable `dt` to the date, but never do anything with it... why? Is the "FilePathHere" a valid (absolute) path? Do you have permission to write to that directory? Could you make the code print some information to the debug window (e.g. `Debug.Print "Processing item " & itm.Subject`) to see when / where it stops working?

Comment: Have you tried deleting the rule and re-creating it? How are you running the rule Manuel? remove `Set objAtt = Nothing` from your code- `Original code:` and put the code in new module1- make sure you don't have duplicate module names or the same sub procedure names

Comment: I have tried deleting and re-creating. It sometimes makes it work for a day or so (And only some of them!), then stops working again.